# php progress bar for fields

Tags: php, progress-bar

i have a site contains 5 fields the user fill it to update his info i have a progress bar in user page i need the progress bar number show depends on the user fields if he fill 4 fields the progress = 80 if he fill only 3 progress = 60 and so on whats the right way to do that because i tried a way and it fail

the way i used is that i made a number for every field when the user fill the field the query update the progress table with that number but the problem i faced is every time he update the field the number increase and its now more than 100%

i wish i know how to make this with the right way

Comment: Do you really want a server side implementation or rather a client side one? Aside: Improve your accept ratio!

Comment: You need html&js, why you want to do it using PHP?

Comment: because this is php site contains forms and progress get data from mysql

Comment: @Sirko Hello i need it server side because it will depend on the fields and row from mysql database

Comment: So it is more like a form spread over 5 pages? Currently I don't think I get your architecture right.

Comment: its only one page contain 5 input fields the user may fill and may not i need the user to see progress for the fields if he fill all fields and its ok it show 100% else it show 80 Or 60 or 0 depends on the fields he fill

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can try this code, using `array_keys` and `count` you can do this.

```
 foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
      if ($value != ''){
          $actual= count(array_keys($_POST, ""));
      }
    }

    $count = count($_POST)-$actual;
  //$count = (count($_POST)-$actual)-2;
```

Based on the count value you can `insert/update` the db table

```
if($count == 1){
    $progress = '20%';
}else if($count == 2){
    $progress = '40%';
}else if($count == 3){
    $progress = '60%';
}else if($count == 4){
    $progress = '80%';
}else if($count == 5){
    $progress = '100%';
}else{
    $progress = '0%';
}
```